# How add animation to a background in horizontal view?

Tags: android, android-animation

I added a blue colour to my horizontal view background! But instead of blue, I need to add ocean like background with a little bubble to the layout. I searched and didn't find a solution.

my Layout is:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/switcher_view"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:background="@color/background_light">
        <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/switcher_scroller"
                              android:background="@color/blue_200"
                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="match_parent"
                              android:scrollbars="none">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/switcher_container"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Currently, it looks like:

[image]

Instead of static blue, I need some bubbles and animation that resembles a water!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the task very simple..first make changes in your layout like this..

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/switcher_view"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/vView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <HorizontalScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/switcher_scroller"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/switcher_container"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </FrameLayout>
```

and then make a video of your animation..store that mp4 file in raw folder of resources..(writing animation and hitting it will be bit harsh on gpu rendering)..

```
VideoView view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vView);
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
view.start();
```

you can detect the completion of video and can replay it using the following code..

```
view.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                view.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes!! Worked :)